# Should i use Object or Class in a Kotlin library

Tags: class, kotlin, object, android-library

I'm writing a Kotlin library for an app. This library gathers information like events, errors, device info to analyze later.

I used Objects instead of Classes for ease of use. Example object from library:

```
internal object LoggingModule { ...lots of methods to use internally... }
```

But i wonder if it's better to use Classes instead of Objects in libraries? Because there is a public method to stop info gathering on library initializing and since there is this feature, also there is no need to create classes on app initializing (meaning Objects) if this feature selected. But i don't think there will be a huge impact on app either.

init example:

```
class App: Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        MyLibrary.setThings(myParameters).setEnabled(true).init() 

    }
}
```

What should i do? Are Objects not a good idea in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects are singleton and static in Kotlin.

The answer to the question has to do with shared state.  Singletons should be stateless, with nothing shared.

I am suspicious of dogmatic ideas like "I only use X; I never use Y."

Better to understand the differences and apply them appropriately on a case-by-base basis.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and sorry for late reply. In the light of your answer, i decided to use Class instead of Singleton for my modules. And Singleton just for my main class (to prevent initializing it multiple times around application). Then i only expose my main class to the application, it seems right to me now.